# Conditional Statements and multiple functions

Tags: python

My task is to:

1. Define a function check_age that takes age as a parameter.
2. If the age is at least 18, you return a string allowed.
3. If the age is anything else, you return a string not allowed.
4. You define a function enter_scrollbar.
5. You ask the user for his / her name "What is your name? ", and assign the input value to a variable.
6. You ask the user for his / her age "How old are you? ", and assign the input value to a variable.
7. You call the function check_age() and give it the age as a parameter (inside the parenthesis). The returned string of the the function is stored in a new variable (i.e. legal).
8. You print a personalized message to the user about if he / she is allowed to drink. Your output should look similar to Welcome _____. You are __________ to drink beer.
9. Call the function enter_scrollbar() to run your code.

This is my code so far:

```
def check_age(age):
    """This function checks wether the person is allowed to drink based on age."""
    if age >= 18:
        return "allowed"
    else:
        return "not allowed"

def enter_scrollbar():
    """This function checks for name and age."""
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    age = int(input("How old are you? "))
    
check_age(age)
message = f"Welcome {name}. You are {legal} to drink beer."
enter_scrollbar()
```

I think I am having some trouble calling the functions or defining them. I get this error message:

```
NameError: name 'age' is not defined
```

Comment: first of all you should be calling the `enter_scrollbar()` function first as it is the one that gets the info from the user. second of all, you should return the values you get from the user inside the `enter_scrollbar()` to use them later like this `name, age = enter_scrollbar()`

Comment: What is `legal` supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `age` variable inside the function. That is why it is not accessible outside.

Here is a solution;

Make the age variable global. In python you can use `global` keyword to make a variable global so that it is accessible even outside the function.

Here is the code;

```
def enter_scrollbar():
    global age
    """This function checks for name and age."""
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    age = int(input("How old are you? "))
    

def check_age(age):
    """This function checks wether the person is allowed to drink based on age."""
    if age >= 18:
        return "you are allowed"
    else:
        return "you are not allowed"

    
enter_scrollbar()
print(check_age(age))
```

Comment: Here are some more details over global and local variables; https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp

Comment: And anyway this is completely not necessary here... No need for global variables. Simply return them from the functions

Comment: Sorry just forgot to write one more line. We can use global in the first step also to update the global variable.

Comment: That was just a mistake, posted the same solution twice. Sorry for that.

Comment: Check my answer. I also added code, used global and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your not defining age out of the funtion. You need to return name and age and set them to a variable, if that makes sense. Try this:

```py
def check_age(age):
    """This function checks wether the person is allowed to drink based on age."""
    if age >= 18:
        return "allowed"
    else:
        return "not allowed"

def enter_scrollbar():
    """This function checks for name and age."""
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    age = int(input("How old are you? "))

    return name, age

name, age = enter_scrollbar()
 
legal = check_age(age)
message = f"Welcome {name}. You are {legal} to drink beer."
print(message)
```

Answer (score -1):

Guesstimating that it is an indentation issue

```py
def check_age(age):
    """This function checks wether the person is allowed to drink based on age."""
    if age >= 18:
        return "allowed"
    else:
        return "not allowed"

def enter_scrollbar():
    """This function checks for name and age."""
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    age = int(input("How old are you? "))
    
    legal=check_age(age)
    message = print(f"Welcome {name}. You are {legal} to drink beer.")
enter_scrollbar()
```